# How to store TimeZoneInfo objects in a database?

Tags: .net, database, timezone

Somewhat misleading title, I know. Never actually wanted to store `TimeZoneInfo` object themselves: rather, I want to store some culture-neutral identifier, which can then be later used to reconstruct an instance of `TimeZoneInfo`.

Currently, I'm storing the value of `TimeZoneInfo.Id` property and it seems to be OK both on English and Russian versions of Windows, but I just wanted to make sure I do the right thing.

Comment: not sure but check this may help you : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/15/sql-server-datetime-function-switchoffset-example/

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Comment: One downside of TimeZoneInfo.Id is that some names are confusing. A client thinks there's a bug since the ID value for Dubai (UTC+4) is 'Arabian Standard Time' which is the normal/vernacular name for the time zone in Saudi Arabia (UTC+3). We tell the client that it's correct (and to not look in the database), but it doesn't make us look good ... I think that generally the TZ names are better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, `Id` is a non-localized identifier, so that's an appropriate thing to store.

You should be aware of one possible problem though: identifiers can change over time. I don't know whether it's an issue in *Windows* time zone identifiers, but it certainly occurs in the Olson (zoneinfo) database. For example, I was recently looking at an issue caused by "Pacific/Ponape" changing to "Pacific/Pohnpei".

I suspect that as Microsoft has tighter control over the IDs, they're more likely to remain the same - but even so, countries can change their names, split into different countries (potentially creating new time zones) etc.

I'm not suggesting any *fixes* for this problem - just highlighting it as a potential issue. Storing the ID is probably the best approach available, but be aware of the potential risks...

Comment: Is there an integer correspondence to the string Id for TimeZoneInfo?  Wonder why they didn't provide an int for Id?

Comment: @ray247: I'm not aware of any mapping between time zone IDs and integers.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see an issue with storing the IDs, as they appear to be a constant value across the windows platform - that is, a specific ID will always map to the same `TimeZoneInfo` object, regardless of which version of windows you use.

I am not sure what mono does, but I would not be surprised if this would be the same. You can always check the [class source code](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System.Core/System/).

Answer (score 0):

check these two methods

```
public static System.TimeZoneInfo FromSerializedString(string source)
public string ToSerializedString()
```

these should preserve as much info as possible :)

Comment: Sure, but are these serialized representations culture-agnostic?

Answer (score -2):

I simply used TimeZoneInfo.Id.GetHashCode(). According to tests, this generates unique integer ID's that can be stored in a DB. You can also build a Dictionary with keys being these hash codes and values being the original ID strings to make reverse lookup easier.

Comment: Of course this just hashes the Id string. If the underlying string changes per the marked answer above; the hash would change.